# Treat all GridView as one?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Floor 1" Foreground="Black" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True" x:Name="Floor1" ItemClick="Floor1_Clicked" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{x:Bind F1}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:RoomChatDataFloor1">
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Floor 2" Foreground="Black" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True" x:Name="Floor2" ItemClick="Floor2_Clicked" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{x:Bind F2}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:RoomChatDataFloor1">
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

I try to create my House a multi GridView display information for each "floor"
But then, I have come to realize setting multiple gridview like this will make the code messy and set multiple Functionality is a waste of time. Is there anyway to treat it as 1 GridView ? All the gridview each floor show the same content. But because of the separation "which floor is it?" I have to do this

Comment: Note that you could also abstract your repeated content (StackPanel+GridView) into a custom made user control; and then use that (repeatedly) in your window. Or are you _specifically_ looking for a way to solve it with a single grid?

Comment: You can use Listview  if your data have some some fixed format.

Comment: Ya! I try to create them using a single Grid, but the Grid only show what the data provide not a "custom look" like I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can create the GridView as custom control and capsulate the functionality that you want.
[How to create custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-2/cc295235(v=expression.10))